# Problem with transparent png display on iPads using Safari

Tags: ipad, webkit, png, transparent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Alpha transparent PNGs not displaying correctly in Mobile Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374618/alpha-transparent-pngs-not-displaying-correctly-in-mobile-safari)

I have a problem with transparent pngs not displaying properly. I am using a 1x1px png (saved for web) repeated horizontally and vertically and when browsing with an iPad, parts of the background get choppy or turn a different color. What could be causing this?

Here is a screenshot of what I'm talking about.

http://img204.imageshack.us/img204/9015/photo1j.png

I should note that there is no problem across all browsers on Win7. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

This problem has been noted and answered here: [Alpha transparent PNGs not displaying correctly in Mobile Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374618/alpha-transparent-pngs-not-displaying-correctly-in-mobile-safari/2665221#2665221)

I tested Dr. Cheap's answer and found it accurate: change your 1x1px transparent png to 2x2px and it will display correctly.