# iPhone 4 adding yellow to stripes to an element

Tags: iphone, html, css, safari

I have an issue with iPhone 4 adding some yellow stripes to an element with a white to grey gradient.

I have attached an image to show what it renders like on the iPhone.

[image: comparison]

It's not happening on previous versions of the iPhone or android phones.

Does anyone have any idea's as to why this might be happening?

Comment: Is it an image or a CSS3 gradient property?

Comment: It's a repeated background image.

Answer (score 1):

what are the dimensions of the image? I ran across a similair issue before, and I had to play with the image width a bit to get it to scale properly.

I fixed my issue using this: [Alpha transparent PNGs not displaying correctly in Mobile Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374618/alpha-transparent-pngs-not-displaying-correctly-in-mobile-safari/2665221#2665221)

Hope it fixes your issue too!