# PNG not displaying correctly on iOS/MacOS

Tags: css, ios, macos, png, bootstrap-5

I'm using a logo as the navbar toggler for 768px screens and below. On the developments tools and android it works as intended with the PNG preserving its alpha channel.
[image: Android Screenshot of Logo with PNG working as it should]

However, I have tested it on an iPhone 8 and get the following result in multiple browsers.
[image: iPhone Screenshot of Logo that has some transparency but an added white background]

I then tested it on MacOS Big Sur and get a similar issue but only with Safari.
[image: MacOS Big Sur Screenshot of Logo that has no transparency but an added white background]

The code below is the styling that I have for this element.  I have tried it as just an img in html, or a picture by itself.  My latest attempt with the background property is after following some answers from stack.

```
.logo-nav-toggle {
        width: 75px;
        height: 100px;
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) url('/src/img/d_labyrinth_transparency_75x100.png') no-repeat center center;
      }
```

Here is the PNG that I am using:

[image: PNG I am using]

A copy is available here:
[image]

Any ideas what the solution to this could be?

Comment: Could you expand on what the use of rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) in the background is to be?

Comment: This was just the latest iteration on the advice from other forum posts such as this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13100847/transparent-pixel-renders-different-on-pc-and-iphone?noredirect=1&lq=1

I have tried it simply as:
background: url('/src/img/d-labyrinth_transparency_75x100.png

Which yields the same results