# png transparent area is white on an iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm dynamically loading a png logo image with transparent background. So basically the logo is colorful and the background is transparent.

But why is the image transparent area white when viewing the webpage on an iPad device?

Comment: Do you have some code or an example? Is it working in desktop?

Comment: @lharby: thanks. I just want to know if there is a common issue with transparent PNG on iPad/iPhones? Yes, the transparent area stays as transparent when viewing on the normal PC browser.

Comment: Are you using a css reset?

Comment: @henry: thganks. No, I'm not using css reset.

Comment: @Beki I have never encountered any issues displaying transparent PNGs on the iPad or iPhone.   Are you sure the element (div, span, etc.) that you are placing the image into isn't assigned or inheriting a white background in your CSS?

Comment: fwiw, you can run Safari's (limited, for html/css developers) inspector on a connected iOS device or on Xcode's iOS simulator. Connect your phone or open the simulator, open up Safari, and you'll find it in the iOS agent in the developer menu (you may have to enable that menu first)

Comment: great! did you figure out what was going wrong? if it's something that might be useful to others, this is the place to document it

Answer (score 1):

This question is already answered: [Alpha transparent PNGs not displaying correctly in Mobile Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374618/alpha-transparent-pngs-not-displaying-correctly-in-mobile-safari/2665221#2665221)

According to his answer you cant use a 1x1px image, but a 2x2px will work perfectly!

Comment: That question is fascinating, but this is not a duplicate: OP is asking an image with some transparent areas

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I solved this, with this css rule:

```css
background-color: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.0);
```